# Rails class method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've a problem with a class method.

I'm writing a quiz app, and I create the method `Quiz.build_quiz` to generate a quiz taking some random questions from another table.

These are my classes

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quiz_questions
  has_many :questions, through: :quiz_questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions

  def self.create_quiz(quiz_type = 'base')
    q = Quiz.create
    q.questions << Question.order_by_rand.all
    q.save
  end

end 

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
  has_many :answers
  has_many :quiz_questions
  has_many :quizzes, through: :quiz_questions

  def self.error_count
    self.sum(:quiz_errors)
  end
end
```

If I try in console to create my object everything is fine, but when I call the method the association is empty.
Where is the error?

:(

Edit: i try also in this way:

```
def self.create_quiz(quiz_type = 'base')
    q = Quiz.new
    q.questions << Question.order_by_rand.all
    q.save!
    return q
  end
```

Comment: return the `q` object at the end of your class method and then see if its association is empty

Comment: I try is still empty

Comment: what do you get if you type `q.errors` ? maybe it's not saving for some reason.

Comment: how can I log errors for class method?

Comment: I meant the errors for the Quiz object you are creating , after `save`. so if you do something like `result=Quiz.create_quiz` you can then check for errors by typing `result.errors` in console. provided you return the `q` object in your class method

Comment: no errors... @messages={}

Comment: To @ali, save! (with the '!') will throw an exception if there is some errors. So the problem doesnt come for sure from a validation error.

Comment: It's true, but the errors must be available through `object.errors` as well if you don't use `save!` and it's weird you are not getting them.